# Update Row ID using Order By [Help]

Tags: sql

I can't seem to get this query to work I am pretty sure I have it correct but i keep coming up with errors.  I am trying to create a update query to the rows and they way they are sorted by using a where clause to a specific section as well as a join.

Here is my query:

```
With cte As
(
SELECT Products.Products.PartNumber, Products.Prices.ProductID, Products.Prices.CODE, Products.Prices.Price
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Price DESC) AS RN
FROM Test
JOIN    Products.Prices
ON      Products.Products.ID = Products.Prices.ProductID
where partnumber like 'l2%'
Order by Price Desc
)
UPDATE cte SET Number=RN
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your cte is a derived table that exists in RAM only.  It's not updateable.  Are you trying to update an actual table?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the row in the table, you could create a VIEW using your ORDER BY query and other queries could check the view instead of the row.

If you want to stick to just your table, you need to check and make sure the ROW ID being set isn't conflicting with any other row. For instance, if you ORDER BY and find row with ID=6 to be the first in the new query, you update it with ID=1. However, row 1 already has ID=1, and that conflicts with your new row ID (Previously row ID=6).